# Communicate between classes in java

Tags: java, class

Im new to java and got a question about communication between classes. Say I got this example below.

1. I got one String (print) that Im sending to a setter-method in MyClass1
2. In MyClass1 I change the string in the getterMethod and ad "1"
3. I receive the manipulated string in the mainclass and send it to setter-method in MyClass2
4. In MyClass2 I change the string one more time and ad " and 2" so the full string is "print 1 and 2"
5. Then i receive the new string in the mainclass through the gettermethod in MyClass2 and prints the result in the main method

The result is "print 1 and 2"

This works fine but are there a better way of communicating between classes. For me it seems like a long way to go through the mainclass. Is it possible to communicate direct between MyClass1 and MyClass2 without first going through the mainclass?

**So my question is:** I there a better way doing this?

Here is my working code:

**Main Class:**

```
public class Testing1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String print = "Hello world";

        MyClass1 m1 = new MyClass1();
        MyClass2 m2 = new MyClass2();

        m1.setPrint(print);

        m2.setPrint(m1.getPrint());

        System.out.println("m2 = " + m2.getClass2());
    }
}
```

**MyClass1:**

```
public class MyClass1 {

    private String print = "";

    public MyClass1() {

    }

    public void setPrint(String print) {
        this.print = print;
    }

    public String getPrint() {
        String print2 = print+" " + 1;
        return print2;
    }
}
```

**MyClass2:**

```
public class MyClass2 {

    private String print = "";

    public MyClass2() {

    }

    public void setPrint(String print) {
        this.print = print;
    }

    public String getClass2() {
        String print2 = this.print + " and 2";
        return print2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Depends what MyClass1  and MyClass2 is :) in java classes are like template of things, and objects are instances of that templates. For example if MyClass1 is Home, and MyClass2 is Dog you can put Dog as private variable in class Home etc. Just start thinking about classes like real objects :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The whole point of good OO design is: some object A should have access to *other objects* that it needs to do its job.

Meaning; normally your classes look like:

```
public class Foo {
  private final Bar bar;
...
```

Meaning: any *Foo* object has a field *bar* that holds a *Bar* object; and that this *Foo* object can use to do what *Foo* has to do.

So, if you want that MyClass1 should be doing something with MyClass2, then one class should have a field of that type; and that field is initialized using a constructor for example.

But, on the other hand: the other idea of good OO design is that a class has a specific responsibility. And you want to make your classes "as small" as possible; meaning: you carefully consider which fields you want to have in your classes. In other words: you try to create small, but useful "building blocks". And then, on some higher level, you use the small building blocks to **compose** something "bigger". In that sense, your current implementation (where *main* creates several objects; and calls them separately to achieve some goal is actually a **good** approach). You see, the last thing you want to end up with: a few large classes, that are responsible for "everything"!

Finally: I know that my answer is "pretty generic and abstract"; but so is your example code. Meaning: in order to learn how to create *real* designs; best is to work on *real* problems. You see, the code you posted doesn't do something "useful"; thus it doesn't matter (to much) it is structured. To a certain degree, it is always easier to give specific advise the more specific input/task is at hand.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, getter/Setter model is generally used in Java Beans where these act as a wrapper to actual bean properties. Setter generally validates the data and store the value, whereas getters usually returns the properties values as it is.

Even in general programming, it is better to provide a setter instead of direct field access so that if something comes up in future and some change is required regarding that field, then it can be done easily in setter getter without impacting the code that is using these APIs.

For your example, instead of getter and setter, a single API can be used like. If the value is not supposed to stored at instance level, then this API can be made `static`.

**Example:**

```
class MyClass1{
  static String modifyString(String str){
    if(str == null){
      return null;
    }else{
      return (str + " 1");
    }
  }
}
```